# eliminate one duplicated observation based on two columns with switched values in R?

Tags: r

I know that there are plenty of questions/answers online pertaining to removing duplicates in R, but I have not found one that resembles my problem.

This is an example of what I have:

```
df<-data.frame("col1"=c("a","b","c","d","f","k"),"col2"=c("k","l","m","n","o","a"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

My goal is to eliminate either the first row OR the last row from this dataframe and have the following outcome:

```
 col1 col2
1    a    k
2    b    l
3    c    m
4    d    n
5    f    o
```

thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` to sort the `df` row-wise and then check for duplicates. After that retain only those rows that are unique.

```
df[!duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))),]
#  col1 col2
#1    a    k
#2    b    l
#3    c    m
#4    d    n
#5    f    o
```